# I wrote a code using semantic ui for vertical menu bar ..but it is not stretched to the entire page..so how can i stretch the vertical menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, semantic-ui

I wrote a code using semantic ui for vertical menu bar ..but it is not stretched to the entire page..so how can i stretch the vertical menu ??
    Can anyone help me out in solving this issue??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Contact Page</title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrip.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="ui vertical inverted icon menu">
  <a class="red item">
    <i class="mail icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="teal item">
    <i class="lab icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="green item">
    <i class="star icon"></i>Vertical menu
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written the above code using semantic ui for vertical menu..The problem is that i am not getting my menu stretched to entire page ...
    Here is my vertical menu screenshot what i am getting when i try to run my code.

**I want my vertical menu in the below format**

> vertical menu fully stretched to my page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this two classes : left fixed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/semantic.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui left fixed vertical inverted icon menu">
        <a class="red item"><i class="mail icon"></i></a>
        <a class="teal item"><i class="lab icon"></i></a>
        <a class="green item"><i class="star icon"></i></a>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/semantic.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will just positioning it fixed. He wants it to stretch vertically. You need to add css to the left nav of ```height: 100vh```